# I Can't install Open Suse in Emachine laptop

Tags: suse

I am trying to install OpenSuse 11.1 in my emachine laptop. All are okay except network cards. Suse don't know my network cards in laptop. Network card's vendor is BroadCom. How can I fix it. Or what is the best Linux for Acer emachine laptop.

Comment: This is a better fit for superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

Broadcom and opensuse doesn't mix terribly well thanks to Broadcom's insistence on keeping their drivers under a restrictive license, and Suse's insistence on only shipping free software. You will need to install the broadcom firmware (the package is 'b43-firmware') and then run 'install_bcm43xx_firmware' as root. That will probably get at least your wired network up to a point where you can pull down updates over the Internet.